# Example of a $\sigma$-additive function over a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

While working in measure theory I've decided to study each theorem using a concrete example of concepts I deal with.

In this case, I want to prove that:

> If $\phi$ is $\sigma$-aditive function on a $\sigma$-field, then there exist sets $C$ and $D$
>   of the $\sigma$-field such that $\phi(C)=\sup \phi(B)$ and $\phi(D)=\inf \phi(B)$.

I'm looking for an easy example of a $\sigma$-additive function over a $\sigma$-algebra. When I say an easy example I mean an example which is easy to handle so try to avoid $\mathbb{R}$ or similar.

Comment: Basic case: finite set $X$, sigma-algebra $2^X$, sigma-additive function the size function. Next level: countable set $X=\mathbb N$, sigma-algebra $2^X$, $\phi(A)$ sum of $2^{-n}$ over $n$ in $A$. If you are after signed measures, replace $2^{-n}$ by $(-1)^n2^{-n}$.

Comment: **Hint**: Take a look at Hahn Decomposition Theorem and its proof.

Comment: never knew how to use that theorem. can you elaborate on it?

Comment: The result you are trying to prove can be proved almost exactly as the Hahn Decomposisition Theorem. The hint is to look how Hahn Decomposisition Theorem is proved.